# How to join child rows from another table and display main row only once using GROUP BY in MYSQL?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, join

I have a simple article and comments system with the following tables:

Articles table:

```
ID | Writer | Text
 1 | Bob    | good article
 2 | Marley | read this
```

Comments table:

```
ID | Article_ID | Comment
 1 |      1     |  i love this article
 2 |      1     |  good one
 3 |      2     |  waiting for more
```

I want to select each article with its comments underneath it. I use the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM articles LEFT JOIN comments ON articles.ID = comments.Article_id
```

The expected results:

```
Article 1: good article
Comments: 1 - i love this article
          2 - good one

Article 2: read this
Comments: 3 - waiting for more
```

What I get:

```
Article 1: good article
Comments: 2 - good one

Article 2: read this
Comments: 3 - waiting for more
```

So how do I select each article with its comments and order the articles by id descending and the comments by their ids descending also?

Thanks

Comment: Your query is fine, it should give you the results you want, so maybe the problem is with the php code

Comment: it will display the article for each comment...so article 1 will be displayed twice because it has 2 comments and so on...thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Well,

Actually both your expected result and the result are wrong. How do you handle your data?

The expected result is wrong because any SQL query returns a table as a result. It cannot contain another table in a row.

Your query returns the following result:

---

Article 1: good article

Comments: 1 - i love this article

---

Article 1: good article

Comments: 2 - good one

---

Article 2: read this

Comments: 3 - waiting for more

---

Witch should be enough for you get the relevant data for your page.

But I would suggest breaking it to separate queries, article usually contains a lot of data you don't want to duplicate in your result.

Like that (untested code):

```
$articles_sql="SELECT * FROM articles";
$comments_sql="SELECT * FROM comments";

$articles=$db->query($sql).getResults();

$comments=$db->query($sql).getResults();

foreach($articles as &$article){
    $article['comments']=array();
    foreach ($comments as $comment){
        if($article['id']==$commnet['article_id']){
            $article['comments'][]=$comment;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I could do it in a way like select articles and inside the while loop select the comments but i think there should be a way to do it in 1 query

Comment: Well you can do the following:

SELECT * FROM articles;

SELECT * FROM comments;

and than in a foreach loop combine the two.

Comment: Or select articles and inside the while loop select and display the comments but isn't there a way to combine the 2 queries into 1

Comment: There is of course. The query you showed us yourself =). But that is one of thous cases  when one query is less efficient than two.

Comment: I'm just worried about performance...wouldn't 2 queries be much slower than doing only 1 query??

Comment: I didn't test for actual numbers. But think on that: your article will most likely contain a lot of text. When you join your article with comment it will duplicate all of that text in memory according to the number of comments you have... it is defiantly not the right way. 

Just don't close the connection between the queries and you'll be fine.

Anyway if you are building an application from scratch and don't have a lot of code, maybe a NoSQL database like MongoDB will be a better fit for you. It actually allows operations like that in a very efficient way.

Comment: `I'm just worried about performance...wouldn't 2 queries be much slower than doing only 1 query??` that depends on the latency between your server and the executing script. If they are on the same server, or, perhaps same hosted network with a gigabit link, it could in fact be faster because you aren't returning redundant data.

Comment: Now I try to select articles and inside the while i try to select the comments but it seems that the comments query stops the main query as i get only 1 article and it stops looping after that :(

Comment: @Max Solution looks good and also gives definitive info. But that first statement in the for loop should be outside of it I think.

Comment: Since you want an array of comments for each article,  the array creation should be inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

You have a 1 to many relationship in the comments table, so use that, and left join the article to the corresponding comment, or you could use a RIGHT JOIN on your original query, I believe.

```
SELECT * FROM comments LEFT JOIN articles ON comments.Article_id = articles.ID
```

OR

```
SELECT * FROM articles RIGHT JOIN comments ON articles.ID = comments.Article_id
```

OR I think even

```
SELECT * FROM articles JOIN comments ON articles.ID = comments.Article_id
```

To order by article id decendingthen comment id decending, tack on:

```
ORDER BY articles.ID DESC, comments.ID DESC
```

Comment: Sorry all these don't work...the first one will display the same results as my query (article 1 will be displayed twice because it has 2 comments)...the second and third ones will display articles with comments only and will ignore others...thanks :)

Comment: Whenever you do a 'select *', you are selecting every column in all tables listed.  I don't think that's what you want.  It sounds like you want to stack the article name on top of the comments, correct?

Comment: i need to select all the columns including the writer and the actual article and the comments and theirs ids

Comment: I think you want to make two separate queries then. You can't do what you want with a single query.

Comment: How about combining join and select 
SELECT a.*,b.* from Articles a JOIN (SELECT * from comments on a.id=b.parent_id) as b

Comment: There is a syntax error in the (select * from comments on a.id = b.parent_id) part...i assume the "on" should be preceded by something missing